# If I know MVC should I also learn regular Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I guess the heart of the question is: "How much commonality is there between Asp.Net and MVC"? For example, from the desktop perspective, either you learn Windows Forms or you learn WPF, and there's very little that the two share in common. If I want to become a master at MVC, is it also worth learning regular Asp.Net? Or is that on its way towards retirement?

Comment: Not really a suitable question for StackOverflow but, yes, they are completely different and no, regular ASP.NET is far from being on its way out. Probably worth a whirl if you have the time.

Comment: Probably best to ask this question on Programmers but IMHO ASP.NET Web Forms is still (and from what Ive read) always will be a first class member of ASP.NET; as with all tech related questions of this sort the answer will always be "it depends". If the firm your working for or will be working for has a need then yes you should otherwise there's little point in learning it just for the sake of learning it.

Comment: I think your question is like discussion subject and it is formulated in a very general way and there are a few things mixed together.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to get at, is MVC replacing regular Asp.Net (which sounds like a no)? So are they complementary? If I learn say, Asp.Net security, will that help with MVC security - that sort of thing.

Comment: Yes a lot of (most) of the security principles are the same ... Same infrastructure.

Comment: Oh I see, so "same core infrastructure", but different "presentation", i.e. webForms vs. mvc? ~something~ to that effect?

Comment: It's worth knowing both, to increase your employment prospects. There is some overlap between the 2, but there are also a lot of differences. I'm the other way round, learning MVC after years of Web Forms, because I feel it's necessary now that MVC has grown in popularity. If you can spare the time, then learn Web Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "regular ASP.NET" you mean WebForms ? Since Web Forms and MVC are build on top of ASP.NET (and share the pipelines) the question transforms to Web Forms vs MVC (seriously that's been debated a million times), whatever does the job. If you're looking into unit testing and more control, I strongly recommend you stick to MVC. That's not to say that unit testing is not achievable in Web Forms, just much harder.

Check those links out:

http://blog.gadodia.net/choosing-between-webforms-and-mvc/

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/13/future-of-aspnet.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942833.aspx

Comment: So outside of just the "presentation" aspect (webforms vs. mvc) everything about the two is the same, and learning core Asp stuff will help regardless of whether I'm using WebForms or MVC? (Is that correct?)

Comment: They both (WebForms and MVC) share the same infrastructure, however they work on different principles, however if you learn how ASP.NET (itself, not that much WebForms) works, your knowledge wont be wasted if you move to the other "platform".

Comment: Added some more links for you :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

WebForms and MVC share a common pipleline up to a point, and then diverge.  WebForms in recent versions has been gaining many of the features found in MVC, such as Routing and Model Binding, but what primarily separates the two is the the Server Control Architecture, and the fact that WebForms is "page based" while MVC is "controller based".  That is, in WebForms everything revolves around the page, while in MVC everything revolves around the controller.

Both WebForms and MVC have their own "pipeline" that defines extension points, and interception points (events or replaceable components).  WebForms is more "event driven" than MVC is, and you tend to have to subscribe to various events in the pipeline to get stuff done.  In a way, there's a strong corollary between WebForms and Windows Forms and MVC and WPF (although WPF uses MVVM rather than MVC, it's actually similar enough to make the analogy work).

You will probably find that 90% of the development work out there in ASP.NET is WebForms at this point, and there will likely be lots of legacy code, so it's probably important to learn it, unless you simply don't want to work with WebForms and are willing to limit yourself.

WebForms is not "dying" or "going away" and has been receiving active development.  I don't think it will be replaced by MVC, but will continue to be offered along side MVC, and the two may actually merge at some stage (although I think that would be many years down the road, as WebForms would have to change substantially).